# "wash your hands" and "wash the hands" difference

Tags: articles

everyone. Could anyone help me to clarify why people say 'wash your hands' all the time? There are a lot of articles on Internet about 'wash YOUR hands', but I've never seen 'wash THE hands'? Why don't we say 'wash the hands'?

The sentences:
1) Before lunch you need to wash your hands.
2) Mom, I don't want to wash my hands They're clean.

The same thing with 'brush YOUR teeth', 'wash YOUR face', 'comb YOUR hair'.
Why do we need to use "possessive pronouns" instead of "the".

Could you please give me a couple of examples with "the"?

Comment: One would say "wash the hands" when referring to cleaning a clock.

Comment: Or when cleaning up a mannequin.

Comment: It's just the way you do it in English.If you don't say 'your', people wonder whose hands you're washing. In languages that say 'wash the hands' (like in Romance 'laver les mains', or I'm guessing in Slavic), if you accidentally say your' ('tes'), people wonder why you're so personal about it. It's just the way it's done, there's no logic to it.

Comment: Are you asking for the "nowadays" reason (why do people say "wash your hands" today), or the historical reason (why did people start saying "wash your hands" in the first place)?

Comment: It’s unclear why you’d prefer “the” to “your” in this example.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to wash someone else's hands or face (parents do this with young children), brush someone else's hair (hairdressers do this), and brush someone else's teeth (dental hygienists sort of do this). So we use "your" to indicate that the person is doing it to themself.

We can use "the" when referring to the activity in general. For instance, during the Seder (the Jewish Passover meal that contains many rituals), one of the steps is called "washing of the hands", during which the all the participants (or just the leader in less strict sects) each wash their hands.

It's even more common to refer to the activity in general without any article:

> Brushing teeth is important for dental hygiene.
>
> Washing hands frequently helps avoid the spread of disease.

Answer (score 1):

For English speakers today, there's no particular reason for it. I say "wash your hands" because my mother says "wash your hands," and she says "wash your hands" because her mother said "wash your hands."

(I'm using a figure of speech; what I really mean is that I say "wash your hands" because when I was growing up, the people around me all said "wash your hands"; and they said it because that's what people said when *they* were growing up.)

It would be interesting to see how English got that way in the first place—how did people say "wash your hands" in Old English? However, I wasn't able to find any information about that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there an exhaustive list of phases such as 'wash YOUR hands'? I think, we are too specific when we talk about our body parts. Any other situations?